# How to use any logic to color text in Python template using HTML?`

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am using Python to draft a Table for the mail. In the mail I will be needing to color the text if that text is of some text value. Say if the text contains "Successful" then the text will be colored as "GREEN". I am using the Python string template to make a HTML snippet.The $w__ are the variable which contains the text. I would like to change the colors of the text based on the text. Please help me out.

```
'''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XXXXX</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
              }
         th,td{
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 7%;
           }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    <p2>Hi All,</p2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p2>SOME_TEXT</p2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>22a</th>
                <th>22r</th>
                <th>29a</th>
                <th>29c</th>
                <th>ICAL</th>
                <th>22g</th>
                <th>22x</th>
                <th>22hm</th>
                <th>28a</th>
                <th>20a</th>
                <th>20b</th>
                <th>20m</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>AM</td>
               <td>$w21</td>       
               <td>$w22</td>
               <td>$w23 </td>
               <td>$w24</td>
               <td>$w25</td>
               <td>$w26</td>
               <td>$w27</td>
               <td>$w28</td>
               <td>$w29</td>
               <td>$w210</td>
               <td>$w211</td>
               <td>$w20m_3<td>
           </tr>

           <tr>
               <td>LA</td>
             <td>$w31</td>
               <td>$w32</td>
               <td>$w33</td>
               <td>$w34</td>
               <td>$w35</td>
               <td>$w36</td>
               <td>$w37</td>
               <td>$w38</td>
               <td>$w39</td>
               <td>$w310</td>
               <td>$w311</td>
               <td>$w20m_4<td>
           </tr>          
        </tbody>
    </table>
<p2>Best Regards</p2>
<br>
<br>
<p2>XXX ---- REGARDS(STATEMENT)</p2>

</body>
</html>
'''
    s=Template(bdy).safe_substitute(w21=xxx[0][0],w22=xxx[0][1],w23=xxx[0][2],w24=xxx[0][3],w25=all[0][4],w26=all[0][5],w27=all[0][6],w28=all[0][7],
                                    w29=all[0][8],w210=all[0][9],w211=all[0][10],w20m_3=all[0][11],
                                    w31=xxx[1][0],w32=xxx[1][1],w33=xxx[1][2],w34=xxx[1][3],w35=all[1][4],w36=all[1][5],w37=all[1][6],w38=all[1][7],
                                    w39=all[1][8],w310=all[1][9],w311=all[1][10],w20m_4=all[1][11])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic style to add class and append that class in td.

```
<style>
.success {
  background: green
}
.error {
  background: red
}
<style>

<td class="success">AM</td>
<td class="success">$w21</td>
<td class="error">$w21</td>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XXXXX</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
              }
         th,td{
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 7%;
           }
           .success {
             background: green
           }
           .error {
             background: red
           }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    <p2>Hi All,</p2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p2>SOME_TEXT</p2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>22a</th>
                <th>22r</th>
                <th>29a</th>
                <th>29c</th>
                <th>ICAL</th>
                <th>22g</th>
                <th>22x</th>
                <th>22hm</th>
                <th>28a</th>
                <th>20a</th>
                <th>20b</th>
                <th>20m</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td class="success">AM</td>
               <td class="success">$w21</td>       
               <td>$w22</td>
               <td>$w23 </td>
               <td>$w24</td>
               <td>$w25</td>
               <td>$w26</td>
               <td>$w27</td>
               <td>$w28</td>
               <td>$w29</td>
               <td>$w210</td>
               <td>$w211</td>
               <td>$w20m_3<td>
           </tr>

           <tr>
               <td>LA</td>
             <td>$w31</td>
               <td class="success">$w32</td>
               <td>$w33</td>
               <td class="error">$w34</td>
               <td>$w35</td>
               <td>$w36</td>
               <td>$w37</td>
               <td>$w38</td>
               <td>$w39</td>
               <td class="error" >$w310</td>
               <td>$w311</td>
               <td>$w20m_4<td>
           </tr>          
        </tbody>
    </table>
<p2>Best Regards</p2>
<br>
<br>
<p2>XXX ---- REGARDS(STATEMENT)</p2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I need to have a logic by which this color can be used according to the text inside the table cell, Let us assume that the cell says successful then the color would be green or if it says not successful then it would be red . And moreover we need to remember this lines will be inside a python string template. Please help me with it.

Comment: @ShankhadipKundu u have to build logic in data. u have to take dictionary(map) flat array, not possible of tricky